# Array bidimensional não altera valor da segunda posição do array

Tags: php

Eai rapazeada!
 
Estou fazendo um protótipo de sistema de pedidos.
 
Minha idéia: Tenho uma lista de produtos e quando usuário clica no mais ou menos do item, eu chamo uma função javascript para alterar a quantidade do produto e ela chama, via ajax, uma rotina php que ajusta a quantidade dos itens solicitados em uma sessão.
Meu problema é que não estou conseguindo alterar o valor da segunda posição do array bidimensional. Eu já pedi pro apache me mostrar qual o valor da posição e ele mostra, mas se eu preciso somar um ou subtrair um mas ele não altera o valor original.
 Segue código:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
session_start();
//unset($_SESSION['ItensPedido']);
//$codProd = $_GET['cod'];
//$conta = $_GET['conta'];
//$existe = 0;
$codProd = 20;
$conta = 1;
$existe = 0;
if(!isset($_SESSION['ItensPedido'])){
    $_SESSION['ItensPedido'] = array();
    array_push($_SESSION['ItensPedido'], array($codProd,1));
}else{
    foreach($_SESSION['ItensPedido'] as $item){
        if($item[0] == $codProd){
            if($conta == 1){
                $item[1] = $item[1] + 1;
                echo "<pre>", print_r($item, true),"</pre>";
            }else{
                if($item[1] != 0){
                    $item[1]--;
                }else{
                    unset($item);
                }
            }
        $existe++;
        }
    }

    if($existe == 0){
        array_push($_SESSION['ItensPedido'], array($codProd,1));
    }
}
echo "<pre>", print_r($_SESSION['ItensPedido'], true),"</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Quando você faz o `foreach($seuArray as $item)`, o `$item` é uma **cópia** do elemento do array. Ao alterar ele, você está alterando a cópia e não o item original que está no array.

Para usar o item do array, você precisa usar uma referência, como indica a [documentação do foreach](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php).

Outra coisa, o seu unset precisa ser usando o array e seu índice, e não a cópia ou a referência dela. E isso também se consegue com o foreach.

Ficaria algo assim:

```
define ('IDX_PRODUTO', 0);
define ('IDX_QTD', 1);

// exemplo
$pedidos = array(
  // produto, quantidade
  array(1, 20),
  array(2, 40),
  array(3, 1)
);

echo "<pre>Antes do foreach:\n" . var_export($pedidos, true) . '</pre>';


foreach($pedidos as $idxItem => &$item) {
  if ($item[IDX_PRODUTO] === 1) {
    $item[IDX_QTD]++;
  } else {
    $item[IDX_QTD]--;
  }

  if ($item[IDX_QTD] <= 0) {
    unset($pedidos[$idxItem]);
  }
}
unset($item);

echo "<pre>\n\nApós foreach #3:\n" . var_export($pedidos, true) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: ,, valeu! não tinha entendido ainda o porque disso no foreach. Funcionou perfeitamente com os ajustes que me disse para fazer.